# React-Router useHistory throws TypeError

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I am getting a type error while trying to use the `useHistroy` hook in react-router.

This is my login component (copied from https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/create-a-custom-react-hook-to-handle-form-fields.html this tutorial).

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { FormGroup, FormControl, ControlLabel } from "react-bootstrap";
import LoaderButton from "../components/LoaderButton";
import { useAppContext } from "../libs/contextLib";
import { useFormFields } from "../libs/hooksLib";
import { onError } from "../libs/errorLib";
import "./Login.css";

export default function Login() {
  const history = useHistory();
  const { userHasAuthenticated } = useAppContext();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [fields, handleFieldChange] = useFormFields({
    email: "",
    password: ""
  });

  function validateForm() {
    return fields.email.length > 0 && fields.password.length > 0;
  }

  async function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    setIsLoading(true);

    try {
      await Auth.signIn(fields.email, fields.password);
      userHasAuthenticated(true);
      history.push("/");
    } catch (e) {
      onError(e);
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="Login">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <FormGroup controlId="email" bsSize="large">
          <ControlLabel>Email</ControlLabel>
          <FormControl
            autoFocus
            type="email"
            value={fields.email}
            onChange={handleFieldChange}
          />
        </FormGroup>
        <FormGroup controlId="password" bsSize="large">
          <ControlLabel>Password</ControlLabel>
          <FormControl
            type="password"
            value={fields.password}
            onChange={handleFieldChange}
          />
        </FormGroup>
        <LoaderButton
          block
          type="submit"
          bsSize="large"
          isLoading={isLoading}
          disabled={!validateForm()}
        >
          Login
        </LoaderButton>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I get an error when I try to do `history.push('/');`

```
react-dom.development.js:11102 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at Login (Login.js:31)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14803)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17482)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:18596)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:188)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:237)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:292)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23203)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22154)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22130)
Login @ Login.js:31
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:14803
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:17482
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:18596
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:188
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:237
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:292
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:23203
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:22154
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:22130
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:21756
eval @ react-dom.development.js:11089
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:653
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11039
flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl @ react-dom.development.js:11084
flushSyncCallbackQueue @ react-dom.development.js:11072
discreteUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:21893
discreteUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:806
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:4168
```

I am using react 16.13 so I don't believe it is a version error.

I have copied the rest of the tutorial verbatim.

Here are is my router wrapped around my App component:

```
var root = document.getElementById('root');
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from 'react-router-dom'

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <App />
  </Router>, root)
```

Comment: Could you `console.log` the `history`?

Comment: @AdamJeliński my page is blank so I can't really get it to console.log. I tried to useEffect on history object but nothing prints to my screen even a static string console.log doesn't fire. any suggestions?

Comment: You can temporarily remove the `history.push('/')` to avoid the error. A `console.log(history)` should work just fine then, unless there are more issues

Comment: I found the issue for the type-error, I needed to update `react-render-dom` but now my login button gets a `Too many re-renders` problem.